# How to multiply a textbox value by an hidden label number and show the result in another textbox without using button postback

Tags: vb.net

I have two `textBoxes` and a hidden label which has a value of a number (e.g 451).

Now, in the first `TextBox`, when the user enters a number, I want it to immediately multiply the value by that hidden label value, and show it in the second `TextBox`. And, if the user leaves the first `TextBox` and insert numbers in the second `TextBox`, I want it to divide the value by that hidden label number and show the value in the first `TextBox`.

I am able to achieve this using a postback button to get the price on click event. I have tried using `JavaScript`, but it always show me this value "NAN".
 I want to be able to calculate at runtime not after when the user clicks a button. I.e it should dynamically increase at runtime.

Note: I bind this hidden number label on `page.ispostback` in `Page_Load` method, so the `TextBoxes` can multiply or divide its value.

Here's my code

For the first `TextBox`

```
Dim btcamount As Double = txtbtc.Text
buyprice = rec.`TodaybtcValue` * rec.BuyRate
txtprice.Text = FormatNumber(btcamount * buyprice, 2)
```

For the second `TextBox`

```
 Dim btcamount As Double = txtbtc.Text
 buyprice = rec.TodaybtcValue * rec.BuyRate
 txtprice.Text = FormatNumber(btcamount / buyprice, 2)
```

Comment: Can you share the javascript code which you have tried?

Comment: Side note, turn **Option Strict On**.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TextChanged` method of the `TextBox` to create the value to be displayed in the other.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

   Try
     Dim value As Double = 0
     value = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(Label1.Text)
     TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(value)
   Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
   End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

   Try
     Dim value As Double = 0
     value = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(Label1.Text)
     TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(value)
   Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
   End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dipa If you're using `vb.net` as you tagged then yes. Try it see if what's what you wanted.

Comment: its working now...i added autopostback to the tetbox bu the only issue am having now is that it does not calculate immediately. it calculates after clicking outside the textbox area.

Comment: the code is good but it only calculates after i click outside the textbox areas i.e anywhere on the page. it doesnt increase automatically like the way jquery does

Comment: @Dipa, try putting it in the `KeyDown`/`PreviewKeyDown`/`KeyPress` methods?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that regardless of what you do, you will need to postback to get the answer you require with VB.NET (aspx).  You're better off using jQuery (or javascript) to calculate the answer on the client side where the data input is happening.

R/
Prescott ....

Comment: Goes something like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>").bind('input', function() {
            var value1 = $('#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>').val()
            var value2 = $('#<%=HiddenTextbox2.ClientID%>').val();
     $('#<%=Textbox3.ClientID%>').val(value1 * value2);
      });
   });
</script>

Textbox is the textbox you bind the function to

Comment: what about on keypress what should be there?